# How to solve these recurrences?

Tags: calculus

Can anyone help me solve these two recurrences ?

$u(n+1)=u(n)+v(n+1), u(0)=\alpha$

$v(n+1)=\mu v(n)-0.05,v(1)=\beta$

So far, I solved v(n) but I'm getting stuck at u(n)...

$$v(n)={ \mu ^n(20( \mu -1) \beta - 1)+\mu\over 20(\mu-1)\mu}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $u(k) - u(k - 1) = v(k), u(0) = \alpha$.

Now sum both sides of the first equation from $k = 1$ to $k = n$.

I am, of course, assuming that you've computed your $v(n)$ correctly.

Good luck!